# Why does ->save(); doesn't work. error is Foreign key violation

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to update a model and when i save the edit, I get the error "Foreign key violation, The key (country_code)=(HUN) is not present in the "country" table" which is true. I want the key "country_code" to reference on the key "code" on Country.

I have my table society that has  a foreign_key "country_code" that reference on the table Country on its key "code".

My society migration has a line like that :

```
$table->foreign('country_code')->references(Country::getPrimaryKeyName())->on(Country::getTableName())->onDelete('set null');
```

My entity has this :

```
public function country()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Country::class, 'country_code', Country::getPrimaryKeyName());
  }
```

I checked that the country primary key on Country is indeed "code".

I know that it doesn't really respect laravel standard but believe me, if I had the choice, I would have respected them but here I am with these strange keys name.

The keys "country_code" in Society and "code" in Country are string.

Thank you if you can help me with this.
If you need more information, I'll gladly give you whatever can help.

Comment: What is your question? You know you dont have a country with the code `HUN` and try to save another model with `country_code = "HUN"` and it triggers an error.

Comment: No, I don't understand why the update of the model society doesn't work. It gets me the error "Foreign key violation, The key (country_code)=(HUN) is not present in the "country" table".
And indeed, the key country_code is not in the table country. It's supposed to attach to "code" on table "country" but it doesn't work

Comment: Because there is no record with key `HUN`. Show ouput from: `dd(Country::where('code', 'HUN')-first()`

Comment: It's not about `country_code` not present in the "country" table, it's about **NO** "country"  with **"code"** = "HUN" is present in "country" table. So there is no country with code = "HUN" to attach to. which violates the foreign key constraint.

Comment: Oh my god thank you, I figured it out. 
I had a country with the code "HUN " but not "HUN". See the space ? this is the problem.
Thank you very much !

Comment: Well you figured it out more than I figured it out so thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in my column "code" of "country", all my codes had a space after them (for example HUN , IDN ) and I didn't saw the space so it had no match.

The answer to my question was that there was indeed no match to what I was looking for. There was no "HUN" in my column "code" of "country" because there was only "HUN ".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).